# Where can I download previous versions of Websphere Liberty Profile lke 8.5.5.1 and 8.5.5.2

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to check if a problem occurs in previous versions of Liberty. Current version is 8.5.5.3 and I would like to check it on 8.5.5.1 and 8.5.5.2. Is it possible to find it somewhere ?

Looking at the downloads page I can find only the latest version.

https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try from here [Fix list for IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036319). You will find Liberty for Developers in given version as one of possible downloads.